# How to set locale for `LC_MESSAGES` through the config files?

Tags: php, nginx, fpm, php-gettext

In setting up `gettext` for PHP, one needs to declare (among others) these two things (in my example I'm using `en_US`):

```
setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, 'en_US.utf8');
putenv('LANG=en_US.utf8');
```

I was trying to move these things into the PHP configuration file instead, so I've set the environment variable for `LANG` as such:

```
env[LANG] = 'en_US.utf8'
```

Which seems to be okay, and the second command is no longer necessary for it to work.

But there doesn't seem to be any such alternative for the `LC_MESSAGES`. Setting it up as an environment variable in my case didn't work, despite the fact that the documentation for `setlocale()` says:

> If locale is NULL or the empty string "", the locale names will be set
>   from the values of environment variables with the same names as the
>   above categories, or from "LANG".

Because in my case the `LC_MESSAGES` isn't empty, but instead it returns `C`, which i have no idea what it means and where that value comes from.

The closest thing i have found in the `php.ini` file was one called `intl.default_locale`, which I've set to `intl.default_locale=en_US.utf8`, but with no change.

So I'm just wondering if it can be done via config files?